# Upgraded OpenSSL version with HAProxy

Tags: haproxy, openssl

I'll make this short and to the point.  I'm running HAProxy 1.5.5 with SSL support for SSL termination/offloading.  Do I need to recompile HAProxy if I update/upgrade openssl, or just restart the service? I cannot find a way to display the version of OpenSSL that HAProxy is using.

HAProxy 1.5.5 on CentOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HaProxy dynamically links in the openssl libraries. You can find this by running

```
# ldd `which haproxy` | grep ssl
   libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x0000003ea3c00000)
```

So when you upgrade openssl you just need to restart haproxy.

Comment: Thanks, I did use the ldd command, however, I did not see a change after upgrading OpenSSL.  Good to know it's dynamically linked

Comment: It was just a minor version change so the libssl.so.10 will be the same.. if that changed then haproxy ssl wouldn't work.. you'd then need to recompile or install a working package.